# Launch Mist directly on Testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, testnets

How can I bypass the full ethereum chain sync and open in testnet mode? I'm on a Mac.

The full chain sync is taking too long and keeps crashing - all I want to do is test some contract functionality in a Meteor Dapp.

Comment: Testnet requires a full sync as well. The best tool for development is [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc). It simulates a highly configurable blockchain, without needing to mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Mist and geth on the testnet, but the testnet contains around 1 700 000 blocks againt 2 300 000 for the mainnet. So it will take time.
To run geth on the testnet, you just need to execute `geth --testnet` 
To run Mist on the testnet, just select Develop / Network / Testnet

[image]

Otherwise, if you just want to quickly develop a contract and create a dapp (meteor or not), I advice you to try testrpc and truffle.

**- testrpc** allows to create a testing ethereum private blockchain

Installation : `npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc`

Start : `testrpc`

More info: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc

**- truffle** is a framework which will help you to create, test and deploy a contract and also to build a dapp (web3 bootstrap for your contracts) :

Installatiion: `npm install -g truffle`

Setup:

`truffle init` to create a project

`truffle compile` to compile your contracts

`truffle migrate` to deploy your contract on your private test blockchain, or on the testnet or on the libe network

`truffle serve` to run your web dapp (nodejs)

More info: [https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle](http://ttps://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle)

Hope this help.